# Cannot grant File Provider Permissions to com.android.mms

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

I am trying to send a bitmap from the cache directory of my app to another external application by granting temporary read permissions through a file provider. When I select the messaging application on my phone (package name : "com.android.mms") the messaging applications crashes and I get the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri content://com.example.brandon.emojimms2/shared_images/image.png from pid=9804, uid=10024 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

Here is a screenshot of the entire error printout if needed:
[image]

I only get this error when selecting com.android.mms from the intent chooser. Every other application that I choose sends the bitmap without error. Even the messaging system on newer phones (com.google.android.apps.messaging) are able to send the bitmap with the fileprovider without any errors. I checked this with several emulated phones and apps, and the results always come out the same. The only app that I found that has a problem with file provider is "com.android.mms".

Here is the code where I share the intent:

```
private void shareImage()
{
    File imagePath = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "images");
    File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.example.brandon.emojimms2", newFile);

    if (contentUri != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
        shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mContext.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
    }
}
```

I even tried a solution recommended in another stackoverflow post that suggested to grant each individual intent activity write and read uri permissions, but that also did not work.

Comment: Remove that image and post the error log in the normal way as text. Further show the provider declaration in your manifest file.